# Gson jsonParser adds extra "" around the String

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json

```
{
  "country": "US",
  "state": "California"
}
```

which is uploaded to S3. Now I download this json file as a inputStream and I do

```
 InputStream inputStream = s3(reference);
 byte[] readBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(new String(readBytes)).getAsJsonObject();
```

but the json has

```
{
 "country": ""US"",
 "state": ""California""
}
```

Comment: What does `new String(readBytes)` contain? You should probably specify an explicit encoding.

Comment: What do you mean by "the json has"?

Answer (score 0):

> `InputStream inputStream = s3(reference);`

I didnt understand what is `s3()` here.

So I have tried downloading a `JSON` object from a different server using this code:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        byte[] readBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(new String(readBytes)).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(json.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it works fine! So, the problem might be in your `InputStream`. Can't tell for sure though.